# How can I access Queue Name from with in Isolated Service Bus Trigger Azure Function middleware?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-functions-isolated

I'm writing a custom middleware for Service Bus Trigger Isolated Azure Function and how can I access source queue name of the message from with in my middleware?

I tried to look for it in the function context binding data properties but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

We had some information exchange on Twitter. The ask here is not so much for the queue name but to achieve a functionality currently not possible with Isolated SDK - custom retries. My suggestion is to either hold off until the feature is introduced and there's parity with the In-Process SDK or move your function back to in-proc where `MessageActions` are available to control message dispositioning. The good news is the Functions team is actively working on the SDK-type support for Azure Service Bus. That will hopefully be followed by allowing end-user code dispositioning of the incoming message (abandon, complete, defer, or dead-letter).